# Python '\x0e' in character by character XOR encryption

Tags: python, encryption

I am trying to build an encryption system using python. It is based on the lorenz cipher machine used by Germany in WWII, though a lot more complicated (7-bit ascii encryption and 30 rotors compared with the original's 5-bit and 12 rotors).

So far I have worked out and written the stepping system. I have also created a system for the  and chopping up the plaintext. But when checking the output, in character for character (By not stitching together the ciphertext) I got this for hello:

```
['H', 'Z', '\x0e', '>', 'f']
```

I have realised that `'\x0e'` must be some special character in ascii, but I am certain that when the program goes to decrypt it will look at each of the letters in it individually. Can someone please tell me what `'\x0e'` signifies, if there are other such characters, and if there's an easy way to get around it.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I hope you are aware of the relations and differences between bytes, encoding schemes, characters, glyphs, pixels on your screen, etc. but your question reads like you aren't. For starters, read [The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html).

Comment: What a fun project!  Are you also going to be building the decryption software?  Will this project be on GitHub (or something) when you're done?

Comment: Yeah, just about finished now, well atleast on the bare-bones algorithm. Because of the nature of the machine as a XOR cipher with a pseudo-random bit generator, encryption and decryption use the same algorithm with the same key. I will try and upload the source code at some point. Here is the wikipedia page for the Lorenz machine which works in a very similar fashion, though is far less complex: [link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lorenz_cipher)

Answer (score 3):

`'\x0e'` is the ASCII SO (shift out) unprintable character. It is a single character, and any reasonable program dealing with the string will treat it as such; you're only seeing it represented like that because you're `print`ing a list, which shows the `repr` of each value in the list.

As for the question of if there are others, yes, there are 33 of them; ASCII 0-31 and 127 are all generally considered "control characters" which aren't typically printable.

Answer (score 3):

It's the [ASCII](http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/chars/c0.html) "shift-out" control character and is nonprintable.

> A control character which is used in conjunction with SHIFT IN and
>   ESCAPE to extend the graphic character set of the code. It may alter
>   the meaning of octets 33 - 126 (dec.). The effect of this character
>   when using code extension techniques is described in International
>   Standard ISO 2022.